# Configuring a zebra scanner via spp

Tags: android, barcode-scanner, spp

I'm writing an android app, that scans barcodes with a zebra rs6000 scanner connected via bluetooth (spp). So far is everything OK, it works.
Now I'm wondering if it's possible to send feedback to the user like different beep-sounds and/or LED colors on the scanner (whether or not the process behind the barcode was successfull).
I know it's possible to configure the scanner beforehand to make different beeps and show different colors scanning "configuration-barcodes", but I need to change these settings from my app. Has anyone an idea?
Any help would be very appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Got the answer from Zebra Developer Portal:

"Hi, there are APIs to control the RS6000 in the EMDK but I am pretty sure they only apply to a scanner connected in SSI mode.  For SPP connected scanners you are limited to the configuration offered by scanning those configuration barcodes"

answered by Darryn Campbell